# Limiting entry display after a conditional

Tags: channel-entries, conditionals

I want to display 10 entries, only if they pass a conditional.
Right now the channel tag will count *all* entries first, so I end up with less than 10 entries displaying (as some of those 10 don't meet the 'if').

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="tours" limit="10" sort="asc" orderby="departure_date"}
    {if departure_date > current_time}
         [TEN THINGS HERE]
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I can’t use {entry_date} as my ‘departure_date’ - it has to be a custom field.

I tried an embed - but that’s not working for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't the [numeric matching](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#numeric-matching) of the [search parameter](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#search-field-name) help you?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="tours" search:departure_date=">{current_time}" limit="10" sort="asc" orderby="departure_date"}
  [TEN THINGS HERE]
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Well I'll be damned.

Comment: Yep - that's what i'm talking about. That worked, and I learned something. Thanks Robson.

Answer (score 1):

Writing your own query would probably be the most efficient way and would let you pull out exactly what you want.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/query/

Answer (score 0):

I would use a PHP script to get around these kind of hassles. You can use the query module to do some manual *select*s on the database, if you really need to avoid PHP script in your template.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/query/

The ExpressionEngine template parsing engine doesn't provide any means to break out of a `{exp:channel:entries}` loop based on a conditional.

You basically need to break out of your `{exp:channel:entries}` loop once you hit ten entries that satisfy your conditional. There's no viable way to do that, even with an absurd PHP-enabled template, regardless of if it's set to parse PHP at input or output. Templating like this only affords forward progression execution.

I can help you generate a PHP script, or a query module tag, to do what you want... but you'll need to expand your question to include what your field IDs are, if you're using MSM, and other issues. Hope I'm being helpful.

**Edit**

Official edit: If any of the heavy-hitters on this forum know of a way to break out of a EE tag loop (like `{exp:channel:entries}`), please chime in. I might be an idiot.